# my frontend is working but data is not getting sent to the database

Tags: reactjs, database, mongodb, cors, mern

Im building a simple react app but my data is not getting sent to the database, the error is axios error : network error in console the error is net::ERR_CONNECTION_REFUSED, ive been struggling for a week please help. im using mern technology im using port 3000 and 8071 for backend

`my server.js

```
const express = require("express");
const mongoose = require("mongoose");
const bodyParser = require("body-parser");
const cors = require("cors");
const dotenv = require("dotenv");

const app = express(); 
require("dotenv").config();

const PORT = process.env.PORT || 8071;

app.use(cors());
app.use(bodyParser.json());



const URL = process.env.MONGODB_URL;

mongoose.connect(URL, {
    useNewUrlParser: true,
});

const connection = mongoose.connection;
connection.once("open", () => {
    console.log("Mongodb Connection success!");
})

const supplierRouter = require("./routes/suppliers.js");

app.use("/supplier", supplierRouter);

app.listen(PORT, () => {
    console.log(`Server is up and running on port:  ${PORT}`)
})
```

my Addsupplier.js

```
import AdminDashBoard from "./AdminDashBoard";
import axios from "axios";


export default function AddSupplier(){

    const [supplierName, setSupplierName] = useState("");
    const [address, setAddress] = useState("");
    const [contactNumber, setContactNumber] = useState("");
    const [email, setEmail] = useState("");

    function sendData(e){
        e.preventDefault();
        
        const newSupplier = {
            supplierName,
            address,
            contactNumber,
            email
        }
        
        axios.post("http://localhost:8071/supplier/add", newSupplier).then(()=>{
            alert("Supplier Added")
        }).catch((err)=> {
            alert(err)
        })

    }

    return(
        <div>
            <AdminDashBoard></AdminDashBoard>
       

        <div className="container">
            <form onSubmit={sendData}>
  <div className="form-group">
    <label for="supplierName">Supplier Name</label>
    <input type="text" className="form-control" id="supplierName"  placeholder="Enter Supplier Name" 

    onChange={(e)=>{
        setSupplierName(e.target.value);
    }} />
   
  </div>
  <div className="form-group">
  <label for="address">Supplier Address</label>
    <input type="text" className="form-control" id="address"  placeholder="Enter Supplier Address"
    
    onChange={(e)=>{
        setAddress(e.target.value);
    }} />
  </div>
 
  <div className="form-group">
  <label for="contactNumber">Contact Number</label>
    <input type="text" className="form-control" id="contactNumber"  placeholder="Enter Contact Number"
    
    onChange={(e)=>{
        setContactNumber(e.target.value);
    }} />
  </div>

  <div className="form-group">
  <label for="email">Supplier email</label>
    <input type="text" className="form-control" id="email"  placeholder="Enter Supplier email"
    
    onChange={(e)=>{
        setEmail(e.target.value);
    }} />
  </div>


  <button type="submit" className="btn btn-primary">Insert Data</button>
</form>
        </div>
        </div>
    )
}
```

Answer (score 0):

For this path (http://localhost:8071/supplier/add) first try to make a connection with postman  . If its working from postman then try to connect with Frontend , Here you have not added supplier.js so i can not surely answer about api. But from frontend perspective you need to crosscheck connection from backend only work if backend is working perfectly.

Comment: I checked with postman and my backend works and mongodb database gets updated,  but after doing the frontend when i try to insert data im getting the network error, please help

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: Whenever we get network error in frontend it means , frontend api call is having issues or backend is not responding , this two scenarios can be possible mostly.